# Files missing from TFS restore

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I've just created the simplest little project with a `Program.cs` file, checked it in to Visual Studio Online, deleted the project locally, and then tried to get the latest version from the online repository. The program file didn't download, even though Source Control Explorer shows it on the server:

[image]

Any idea why this won't download?

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, you need to right click the solution and select 'Get Latest Version'.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I've already done that and it doesn't come down. That is essentially the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

At this point there are no changes in the files since you last did a Get-latest to your workspace.  Follow the below steps to get the files for your workspace:

- Right click on the file/folder
- Choose Advanced instead of Get Latest Version
- Choose Get Specific Version
- Check the "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version" box

This will force a download of all the files and not just files that have changed since the last time they were retrieved to your workspace.